# Is it possible to set Telnet communication as higher priority than, e.g. file uploads?

Tags: windows, networking, telnet

My understanding of the internet is limited. However, I enjoy playing MUDs which are text games that communicate through telnet. I observe that every time an upload is made through our connection - even small files - it almost always leads to disconnection between MUD server and MUD client (me), and an inability to reconnect until completion of the upload.

Is there some way on Windows 10 -- or, alternatively, Ubuntu 18 -- to 'set' these telnet communications as higher priority than whichever service the uploads are done with?

Comment: It's usually done in the gateway router, add the make/model to the question. It's just a matter of setting telnet to a higher priority than http/https & ftp.

Comment: It's a Baudtec RN243R4-A6. I reset it and entered the superuser mode, though I'm not sure what rules to add in QoS to band-aid fix the problem

Comment: I've experimented by adding a rule that puts communication from port 23 (src and dest) at top priority, though currently I'm not sure if it's quite working. Experiencing no issues

Answer (score 0):

That's a textbook presentation of bufferbloat, which means your router or modem or other networking equipment is complete garbage at managing its backlog of unsent packets when the connection is being fully utilized. The solution is Smart Queue Management (SQM), and the best SQM algorithm is Cake followed closely by FQ-CoDel. Both are available in OpenWrt Linux-based router firmware.

To confirm this diagnosis, run http://dslreports.com/speedtest from a desktop/laptop web browser and check your bufferbloat grade.

If you don't want to mess with OpenWrt yourself, consider buying an IQrouter from evenroute.com. It's a turn-key solution for getting SQM running on your network.

Using QoS to prioritize your Telnet traffic over other traffic is not a solution, it just shovels the problem onto someone else's lap.

Comment: Sadly, my 2 mbps internet has too much latency for that specific test -- it always automatically disables it. But fast.com shows 100 up to 500 ms difference between unloaded and loaded usage. In the long run I would prefer to get my own router, but I currently only want a band-aid as this is a shared apartment network